# React gives warning (Did not expect server HTML to contain a <div> in <div>) when using React.Suspense

Tags: javascript, reactjs, code-splitting, react-suspense, react-ssr

I am building a react app with the `SSR` feature and I am using `React.Suspense` for code-splitting on the client-side and I am getting this warning.

```
 Warning: Did not expect server HTML to contain a <div> in <div>
```

I have my `App.js` file on the client-side as:-

```
import React,{Suspense,lazy} from "react"  
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

const Home = lazy(() =>
  import('./components/Home')
)  
const Post = lazy(() =>
  import('./components/Post')
)  

function App(){
   return(
       <div>
         <Suspense fallback={<div>wait...</div>}>
           <Switch>
             <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
             <Route path="post" component={Post}/>
           </Switch>
         </Suspense>       
       </div>
    )
}
```

I also have an `App.js` file for the server-side, but I am not using `React.Suspense` there as it is not supported on the server. the file looks like below:

```
import React from "react"  
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'  
import routes from './routes'

function App(){
   return(
       <div>
           <Switch>
             {routes.map(({ path, exact, component: Component, ...rest }) => (
                <Route key={path} path={path} exact={exact} render={(props) => (
                <Component {...props} {...rest} />
                )} />
            ))}
           </Switch>
              
       </div>
    )
}
```

My application renders perfectly on the server, but on the client-side, I am getting that `Warning`, also when I remove the `Suspense` on the client `App.js` file everything works just fine.

Could anyone help me with how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Did you mean to write `Switch` instead of lowercase?

Comment: Sorry its just a typing mistake inside the question it is fine on the actual code on my pc I have updated it

Comment: It's quite hard to see how you are generating client and server-side code. Especially when not knowing which router you are using and how you are hydrating the DOM, referring to the example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ssr . Is this really the error: `HTML to contain a in .` ? I as an outside person can not know where `.` is.

Comment: i have updated the error message

Comment: related github issue https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20825